# XPages: Loading Screen while changing Tabs (TabPanel)

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I have a TabPanel on my XPage. When i move from one Tab to another, few data is loading and this takes some time.

Is it possible to show a loading screen, while changing Tabs?

Thanks for your help

Regards

Answer (score 6):

You should take a look at `xe:djTabContainer` and `xe:djTabPane`. That's the XPages extension library versions of the Dojo tab container. It provides support for loading content in all tabs at once or using partial refresh with the option to add a loading message.

**Update**

Paul Withers commented on the `loadingMessage` property. It does work with all content. Here's a simple example:

```
<xe:djTabContainer id="djTabContainer1" doLayout="false">
    <xe:djTabPane id="djTabPane1" title="Tab 1" partialRefresh="true" refreshOnShow="true" partialEvents="true" loadingMessage="LOADING LOADING LOADING">Tab 1</xe:djTabPane>
    <xe:djTabPane id="djTabPane2" title="Tab 2" partialRefresh="true" refreshOnShow="true" partialEvents="true" loadingMessage="LOADING MORE LOADING MORE">Tab 2</xe:djTabPane>
</xe:djTabContainer>
```

When you switch tabs, you can very briefly see the loading message.

Comment: I believe the loadingMessage property is only relevant when loading content from another URL via href property. See p229 of XPages Extension Library, the section on Border Container. (The Dojo container controls all extend the same UIDojoContentPane class, which defines the href and loadingMessage properties.)

Comment: Paul, I have added an example :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standby dialog custom control for that:

http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=standby-dialog-custom-control

It basically injects itself into the partial refresh mechanism. If it takes more than a specified duration for any AJAX request, standby dialog will be shown to the user.

Comment: Check out my answer from this question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103409/execute-standby-dialog-from-link/25115513?noredirect=1#comment39091976_25115513