# XPages: Show busy dialog when tabPanel clicked on?

Tags: xpages

I'm using an XPages Tabbed Panel for the first time.  It's generally working well, but I have a lengthy process that runs the first time one tab is clicked on, so I would like to display a client-side busy dialog that we routinely use when it's switched to.  I've tried to attach some client-side JS to the associated tabPanel's event handler (with submit="true"), but that doesn't seem to work.  It executes the client-side JS, but doesn't switch tabs anymore.  (I am returning true in the client-side event handler.)  Is there another approach that might work?  FYI, I was assuming that I could call view.postScript(...) at the end of my lengthy code in order to remove the busy dialog.

As usual with my questions, I can't post code to demonstrate this, sorry.

Thanks,
Reid

Comment: Have you tried using djTabContainer/djTabPane instead? See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25260393/785061

Comment: I wasn't aware of that and my search here didn't find that question.  Thanks!

Comment: Strangely, I tried using djTabContainer, but a repeat inside the djTabPane wasn't able to access a critical viewScope variable (it was null).  That did work with Tabbed Panel, so I went back to that.  Otherwise, I think it would've worked okay.

Answer (score 1):

I use this post: http://xpagesera.blogspot.com/2012/05/add-ajax-loading-control-in-xpages-for.html

to great effect for this. Here is the text of the post:

Add AJAX “Loading..” control in XPages for Partial Updates

This is a two step process:

1. Add following Dojo modules to your XPage.

   ```
   <xp:this.resources>
   <xp:dojoModule name="extlib.dijit.ExtLib"></xp:dojoModule>
   <xp:dojoModule name="extlib.dijit.Loading"></xp:dojoModule>
   </xp:this.resources>
   ```
2. Add following lines to the EventHandler of your button/link which is going to be used for Partial Update:

   ```
   <xp:this.onStart><![CDATA[XSP.startAjaxLoading()]]></xp:this.onStart>
   ```

That’s all !

A similar “Please wait..” dialog will appear and will display the page again once the Partial Update is complete..

Comment: I am familiar with doing this sort of thing for buttons/links.  Adding an event handler to them is very common.  My question is related to tab panels; I don't think what you're recommending will work there any better than what I've tried.  When I add an event handler, the tab doesn't switch anymore.  But thank you!

Comment: <xp:this.onStart><![CDATA[XSP.startAjaxLoading()]]></xp:this.onStart>
<xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[XSP.endAjaxLoading()]]></xp:this.onComplete>
<xp:this.onError><![CDATA[XSP.endAjaxLoading()]]></xp:this.onError> This is the Event handlers I can't put above (for someone seeing this). Reid - I've actually put these in the click events of the tabs and had them work.

Comment: Thanks, Brian, I will give it a try then.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing as before; the page starts on the first tab, I click on the 2nd, lengthy tab; it does a submit, but stays on the first tab.  I have an <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"> with your lines after it associated with the 2nd tab.  Any idea what's wrong?  (I also don't see any "loading" message.)

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post a working example of how you associate those events with a tab panel, or at least the full relevant bits.  Thanks!